# Getting nextSibling of element using xpath and puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get the sibling text using xpath and puppeteer. I am able to get the parent just fine but I keep getting an object or unable to properly parse what is getting grabbed from page. Some of the elements aren't always available on every page.

[image: Layout of html]

What I am trying to grab

[image: what I am trying to get]

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const C = require('./login');
const {listenPageErrors} = require('./console');
const USERNAME_SELECTOR = 'input[name="login"]';
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR = 'input[name="password"]';
const CTA_SELECTOR = 'button[type="submit"]';
const fs = require('fs').promises;

async function startBrowser() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    return { browser, page };
}

async function closeBrowser(browser) {
    return browser.close();
}

async function playTest(url) {
    const { browser, page } = await startBrowser();
    page.setViewport({ width: 1980, height: 1024 });
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');
    await page.goto('https://f95zone.to/login');
    await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(C.username);
    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
    await page.keyboard.type(C.password);
    await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.goto(url);

    const parent = await page.$x("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]");
    const text = await page.evaluateHandle(el => el.nextSibling, parent[0]);
    console.log(vctxt);

}

(async () => {
    const data = await playTest("https://f95zone.to/threads/amairo-chocolate-2-final-cabbage-soft.165431/");
    // console.log(data)
    process.exit(1);
})();
```

Output of console

```
CDPElementHandle { handle: CDPJSHandle {} }
```

Update thanks to @Yaroslavm

```js
 const element = await page.waitForXPath("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::text()");
const text = await page.evaluate((e) => e.innerText, element[0]);
console.log(text)
```

Outputs undefined but in chrome console

```js
$x("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::text()")[0]
```

This outputs "Japanese" and unsure how to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```js
const element = await page.waitForXpath("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::b");
const text = await page.evaluate((e) => e.innerText, element);
```

Comment: Its a step in the right direction. I was looking for text() ```const element = await page.waitForXPath("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::text()");```

The only issue, is that I am unsure how to get the output of the text itself. Running ```$x("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::text()")[0]``` outputs "Japanese" text but getting undefined when doing ```(e) => e.ANYTHING, element[0]```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to resolve it with

```await page.waitForXPath("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::text()");
    let [element] = await page.$x("//b[contains(.,'Voiced')]//following-sibling::text()");
    let text = await page.evaluate((e) => e.textContent, element);
    console.log(text)```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).